# How can I get specific data from firebase database which key value is e-mail?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to get specific data from firebase. My database look like this:

[image: firebase database user node]

and I can get numara value correctly but my other keys which are E-mail and Kullanıcı Adı I can't get it with javascript because of - character and space. How can I solve it? I really need help.

Here my sample code:

```js
      rootRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

        var user = snapshot.val();
        console.log(user.numara, user."E-mail");
        

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

         

         var childData = childSnapshot.val();
         //console.log(childData);
        });
       });
```

Here `console.log(user)` output.

[image: console output]

Comment: How do you initialize `rootRef`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is purely the `-` in the field name, you can use `[]` notation to get that specific field. Without Firebase that'd look like this:

```
var user = { "numara": "0536...", "E-mail": "ekslg..." };

console.log(user.numara, user["E-mail"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, because you don't provide a lot of information, but I noticed in your code, you're using `user."E-mail"` but your screen capture of the firebase UI actually shows the key as `email`

Could it be that ?

Comment: Sorry I added wrong database, now I add correct user node. (last one for only test)

Comment: can you try with user["E-mail"] ? And if that doesn't work, can do a console.log(user), to see what's inside ?

Comment: ["E-mail"] not working I already tried that. console.log(user) gave me all node's values. I can see user email and username etc. but I need to reach these separately. How can I make that ?

Comment: could you paste the result of the console.log in your question ?

Comment: I pasted console.log(user) output image in question.